# Swipe action binding in knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, dom-events

I am using knockout as main framework in my application and it has to support tablets and mobile devices. As the framework is built on binding handlers I wonder how can custom binding to actions (like swipe and other device specific ones) be achieved, or maybe there is something like this done?

Comment: You're able to add your own bindings: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html

Comment: yes I know. but the thing I am looking for is some nice built in swipe, tap and other touch events bindings (because now I am initializing it on document start with jquery selectors and bind those actions manually)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably too late, but here is a library that adds touch binding to knockoutjs:
https://github.com/yaroslavya/knockouch

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a `bindingHandler`. Here you go an example of a real project

   ```
   ko.bindingHandlers.swipeSections = {
   init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
       var elem = $(element);
       var params = valueAccessor().split('##');

       elem.unbind('swipe');

       elem.swipe({
           swipeLeft: function (event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount) {
               //process
           },
           swipeRight: function (event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount) {
               //process
           }
       });
   }
   ```

   };
2. Using a swipe library: https://github.com/mattbryson/TouchSwipe-Jquery-Plugin

   ```
   script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.touchSwipe.js"
   ```
3. Define the item's binding

   ```
   div id="myid" class="section" data-bind="swipeSections: 'leftPanel##rightPanel'"
   ```

Answer (score 0):

There are no built in bindings for specific frameworks as knockout.js has no dependencies on any other framework. It should be a trivial task to convert your jQuery selector code to binding handlers referencing the link @niko provides above.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if it still helps, but here is a pointer.

1. Use a library like Hammer.js to get multi touch actions.
2. Write a custom binding handler and call the knockout's default event binding. something like this for a swipe. (the author of the fiddle uses tap.js)

http://jsfiddle.net/snaptopixel/spByj/

now all you do in your html is

```
<button data-bind="tap:doSomething">Click Me</button>​
```

where doSomething is a function.