# touch event binding for knockout.js

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, touch

I've just started learning Knockout.js and I've run into some trouble, which I need some help to resolve.

Basically I want to add my touchend event to my Knockout generated list. At the moment I'm doing something like this:

HTML:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: names">
  <li data-bind="text: $data"></li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
var names = ['Tom','Jennifer','Jack','Poul'];

ko.observableArray(names);

ko.applyBindings(names);


$('li').on('touchend, function(){
 ... do something
});
```

But I assume this is not the proper way to do it? How do I 'data-bind' my 'touchend' with Knockout (if thats is the way to do it)?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10446873/swipe-action-binding-in-knockoutjs

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use knockoutjs event binding:

```
 <li data-bind="text: $data, event: { touchend: $parent.touchEndHandler }"></li>
```

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/event-binding.html

You viewmodel binding doesn't look quite right either, try this instead:

```
function NamesViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.names = ko.observableArray(['Tom','Jennifer','Jack','Poul']);
    self.touchEndHandler = function(data, event) {
        var element = $(event.target);
        alert("TouchEnd Triggered");
        // can access self here which is the viewmodel
    };
}

var viewModel = new NamesViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Example - http://jsfiddle.net/infernalbadger/pjG8r/

Comment: You probably wanted to write `event: { touchend: $parent.touchEndHandler }` because in the view the `li` will be inside of the `data-bind="foreach: names"`...

Comment: @nemesv Thanks, just noticed that and was editing as your comment came in :D

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How would you pass 'this' (the touched element) to the 'touchEndHandler' method?

Comment: @RichardDalton what edit? :) Can't see where $(this) / this is passed to the function?

Comment: @MichaelFalckWedelgård I have edited again. The event object passed as the second parameter can be used to find the element that triggered the event. You can get this element using $(event.target)